# Cloudflared tunnel automatic authentication

Tags: cloudflare

I am writing a server application and want to use cloudflared tunnels. From the docs, I am seeing that the first step is to run "cloudflared tunnel login" which opens up a browser in order to authenticate your cloudflare account. Does anyone know of anyway to do this without any user input? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just go to cloudflared website and go to zero trust, then network and finally go to tunnels and there you can create the tunnel, you will have a pem archive and you need to use this to runn the tunnel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).